# Trying to find the name of the movie where young men entered a cyber world and meet a girl with pink hair

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't remember a lot from the movie. I watched it maybe around 2004 to 2011 and all I can remember was that two people (or perhaps more) who were friends in the movie entered some cyber-world. The cyber-world is not futuristic in the sense of flying cars etc. It's just different in that when the characters go there its strange for them and they see like a whole bunch of different people and girls that are dressed erotically and there's a girl with neon pink hair that they end up meeting. I think at the end they were chasing some guy.

I have been trying to figure out what this movie is for the longest time but can't remember what it is please help. The movie is not animated, it's real life.

The following things might have been in the movie:

1. The characters used computers to go in this world.
2. The people who were in the virtual world were obese.
3. One of the characters might have fallen in love with this pink haired girl

It's not sharkboy and lava girl.

Comment: Let's simplify this: Movie, cyber-world, girl with pink hair and chasing scene at the end. Not much to go off, can you add any more details? Language, character/actor names? More of the plot elements?

Comment: Could it be [Sala Samobójców (Suicide Room)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1808454/)?

Comment: Maybe a better description of what made it seem like a cyber world, or futuristic? Were there flying cars, holograms, random lights on the edges of things?

Comment: Any chance it's the Adventures of Shark Boy and Lava Girl in 3D?

Comment: @starpilotsix  i just added more information its not that but thanks a lot for helping

Comment: @DCShannon just added more information

Comment: +1 for adding more details. Not ringing any bells though, sorry.

Comment: @Mooz just added more info and thanks for your help btw

Comment: @DCShannon its cool man

Comment: Animated or live action?

Comment: the movie is yes a real life movie not animated @user867

Comment: [Nirvana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(film)) first came to my mind ([trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zqmaSgmYiQ)), but Gamer sounds like a much better match...

Comment: @starpilotsix: Do you mean "Spy Kids 3: Game Over"? That one takes place (partly) in a video game, and has a similar feel to SB+LG (both made by Robert Rodriguez).

Comment: The feel of the movie reminded me of eXistenZ, but I don't think there's any pink hair there. Gamer sounds right to me too.

Comment: @TMN: No, I chose the one I did because of the pink hair and because the whole "dream world" type thing with heavy CGI could, considering how memories vague things up and how artificial it looked, could have been mistaken for a cyber-world.  Never saw Spy Kids 3 so I didn't know if there was a pink haired girl in it.  (Also with "girl" for some reason I assumed it was a kids movie (the additional information bout eroticism and stuff wasn't yet in the question) so that threw me off course.)

Comment: Maybe it's The thirteenth floor? I don't recall if girl's hair was pink, nor eroticism, but the rest of the clues matches more or less to it.

Answer (score 41):

I believe you're thinking of the 2009 *Gamer* starring Gerard Butler.

In this movie, people connect to *other people*, although it seems like a digital world. People inject themselves with nanites that allow others to completely control them, and connect to a virtual reality system that also lets them experience everything the other person's body experiences.

The pink-haired girl you're probably thinking of is Angie Tillman:

[image: Image of Angie with hair that looks pink under the blue light]

Although her hair is only pink there because of the lighting (other times it's blue), and you usually see her with orange hair:

[image: Angie, with orange hair, and John with a gun]

She's volunteering for a game called "Society", which lets people control her in a way almost like *Second Life*, except they can do whatever they want with the controlled bodies, including making them dress and look how they want, and force them to have sex. There's some very erotic parts to this.

I tried to do a screen cap of a scene that shows when a user connects to this world, but unfortunately the parts that make it seem futuristic contain nudity or are just generally NSFW, so I won't be posting one. However, it happens about 17 minutes into the movie, if you get a copy. This pic of the top gamer playing with the UI in the FPS-game (that the main character is trapped in) is the best I could do, under short notice:

[image: Image of the top gamer playing with the UI]

As far as your obese people go, in this case Angie Tillman is controlled in "Society" by her player, seen here:

[image: Image of morbidly obese gamer]

And yeah, they were chasing a bad guy, who was trying to control nanites in people against their will.

### Trailer

Comment: I'd be *really* surprised if this weren't it.  +1

Comment: @Praxis I recognized it immediately, but couldn't remember the name or actors *at all*. However, I remembered watching it right around when *Surrogates* with Bruce Willis came out, and thinking how odd it was to have 2 movies based on people controlling other bodies come out so close together. Lo' and behold, searching "Movies like Surrogates" popped it right up.

Comment: @CreationEdge its never odd - the movie studios tend to be like sheep, if 1 makes a movie of a certain subject, the others jump on that bandwagon.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - particularly when, as for Surrogates, it's an adaptation of a [pre-existing story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Surrogates) from another medium.

Comment: The response to this question is very unexpected, and very much appreciated. I know comments aren't for thanks, but I'd like to thank you all anyway!

Comment: @CreationEdge yes thats it ty soo much

Comment: @svgewarrior Then would you do me the favor of clicking the checkmark next to my answer, to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Code Lyoko (Evolution?) is the show you might be looking for.

Animated in both CGI, 2D and real actors for earth.

Story about kids were able to enter into some sort of cyber network with artificial intelligence XANA. Also pink haired girl in other world too.They are chasing a bad guy Professor Lowell Tyron. They fight futuristic monsters (where the show then goes into CGI). And when on earth the show use actors. XANA is a artificial intelligence, the kids use computers to get into the other world. Not sure about clothing?? depends on how you look at it. Xana creates plenty of futuristic tech monsters. Yup one of the guys is in love with the pink haired girl. Not sure about fat people... ??

Pictures below

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add any details indicating that this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Is it Tron Legacy? All your requirements fit except the obese people thing. Also I don't remember the girl's hair color.

Comment: Her hair color was Blue

Comment: I don't recall any blue hair in Tron: Legacy. Quorra (Olivia Wilde) had black hair, while Gem's was white (there was a blue tint to most of the lighting, but by comparing the "real world" scenes to the "grid" scenes it seems pretty clear what the actual coloring is.